Pydantic Nested Model Validation
Need help setting up a nested Pydantic model that takes in restricted values
My current code:
class Category(str, Enum):
   Category: 'category'

Class Sub_Category(str, Enum):
   Sub_Category: 'sub_category'

I however want to restrict this to pick up Categories and Sub-Categories that I have already defined in my master category list. For example, Category = 'Meat', then Sub_Category must either be 'Beef', 'Poultry', 'Seafood' .. etc.
Need help, not sure how to make the nested Pydantic models related like how I described above.

This can be solved with a model validator:
from enum import Enum
from pydantic import BaseModel, model_validator
from typing import Union


class Category(str, Enum):
    meat = "meat"
    veg = "veg"


class MeatSubCategory(str, Enum):
    beef = "beef"
    lamb = "lamb"


class VegSubCategory(str, Enum):
    carrot = "carrot"
    potato = "potato"


SubCategory = Union[MeatSubCategory, VegSubCategory]


class Foo(BaseModel):
    category: Category
    sub_category: SubCategory

    @model_validator(mode="after")
    def validate_sub_category(self):
        valid_subcategories = {
            Category.meat: MeatSubCategory,
            Category.veg: VegSubCategory,
        }
        expected_enum = valid_subcategories.get(self.category)
        if not isinstance(self.sub_category, expected_enum):
            raise ValueError(
                f"Sub-category '{self.sub_category}' is not valid for category '{self.category}'"
            )
        return self


try:
    foo = Foo(category=Category.meat, sub_category="beef")
    print(foo)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

try:
    foo = Foo(category=Category.meat, sub_category="carrot")
    print(foo)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

